# How can I reduce the delay of tap click?

Tags: touchpad

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 x64. Everything works pretty fast except when I tap to click it has a delay of about .5 seconds. This is quite a problem since I want to work fast. For example I click on the google input field in the browser and start typing.. about 3 letters are written elsewhere, not in the search bar, also keeps draging and selecting. I cannot be waiting for this much delay on every click and have no liking into being force to use the button below the touchpad. 
I've read something about fasttaps, but that option seems to be missing along with the xorg.conf file and xorg.conf.d folder in etc/X11. Also I am a beginer at Linux.

Details: 
Also got Windows7 on a different partition 
Haven't created a swap file/partition yet
RAM: 2GB
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5800  @ 2.00GHz

Comment: Solved by restarting(after crash. couldn't recover from suspend mode). Did apt-get upgrade and apt-get update. Don't know if that helped. Vote for delete post or mark as solved.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Anything else you tried?